# How to apply patch to a destination original source code as a jar file or maven repository url

Tags: eclipse, patch, tapestry

I want to apply a patch file in eclipse. I just simply followed these steps:

```
Right clicked my project
Team -> Apply patch
File -> Given the input patch file
Apply the patch to the selected file, folder or project -> Selected my project
```

Patch contents show me:

file does not exist

In the patch file, mentioned a source file to change (src/main/java/org/apache/tapestry5/internal/spring/SpringModuleDef.java). But that source file is my framework's tapestry5/internal/spring/SpringModuleDef.java file & I included that tapestry-spring using maven repository dependency.

while selecting the "Apply the patch to the selected file" I don't have the option to select maven things.

So I removed that dependency url & included as a jar in my project, I tried by selecting the jar file, still now the same error throws. I can't be able to apply that patch.

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You are applying the patch to a different folder to where it was created. You will need to apply the patch at exactly the same level/folder as it was created. Usually this is done in the root folder of the `trunk` or a specific `branch` / `tag`.

It seems strange to me that you consider your root to be some arbitrary child folder in source tree. I suggest that you checkout from the root folder and create and apply patches from root.

Comment: How to apply TAP5-1837-2.patch this in my project? can you explain me a bit more? Really struggling with this

Comment: I have no idea what that file is

Comment: NPE on registry startup when using tapestry.use-external-spring-context in 5.3.2

Comment: Nope, that didn't help

Comment: Then how to overcome this NPE error in my tapestry project which caused by that abstract="true" bean

Comment: Using tapestry-spring 5.3.3

Comment: You're lucky I have any idea what you're talking about. I found the patch [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12535064/TAP5-1837-2.patch). It looks like the patch was created relative to [tapestry-spring](https://github.com/apache/tapestry-5/tree/master/tapestry-spring) so you will need to apply it at the same location. It really should have been created from [root](https://github.com/apache/tapestry-5)